# Sync, not import, CSV files with SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite, csv

In MySQL I have observed that under table options, the storage engine can be configured as a CSV file.  This gives me a nice clean csv file in the database directory.  This file doesn't come with column names but this isn't a deal breaker.

Can SQLite be configured to point to or sync with a csv file?  I am **not** just trying to Import data from a csv file into the SQLite database.

If this is not possible in SQLite, I welcome alternative suggestions.

**Big picture**:  This is a portable database that deals with tables of radically different sizes.  Some may have 10 lines.  Other a few hundred, others a few ten-thousand.  Because of the nature of the data, most tables are manually maintained and this is best suited by spreadsheet like interfaces.  Some are the result of an automated process, but in general, they still require some manual characterization in a few columns to Join (via SQL) to the other tables.

Previously I performed all this in Microsoft Access, but because I now need a cross platform open-source approach, I am exploring alternatives. I have had reasonable productivity with MySQL, but I would something a little smaller, simpler, and more portable for my users.

Comment: It sounds like your real problem is you need a user friendly GUI interface to allow people who dont know SQL to manipulate a SQLite database. This CSV thing is one possible solution. Your question would attract better answers if you ask about the underlying problem, rather than if one solution would work.

Comment: @Schwern - Thanks for looking at the question and offering your advice.  I know that fundamentally, inserting and modifying row records is a SQL command, but my users are SQL illiterate and have no desire to use anything other than excel. In my current solution I let them use excel/csv to store their data and edit it as they need, but I need some join queries and a good driver to connect to R, my statistical program.  I also tried to be specific, because I see tonnes of questions attacked for asking "is this the right database for my task"...

Comment: It would be possible to write a [virtual table module](http://www.sqlite.org/vtab.html) for CSV files. There is an [existing one](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/html/csvtable_8c.html), but it's read only.